# AppleScript keystroke sometimes capitalizing letters?

Tags: applescript

I'm actually troubleshooting and Alfred workflow I've been using for a while. The author developed it in 2014 and it's pretty simple, so I'm not sure I'll get much help from their forums. Basically, I have this:

```
set chars to count (get the clipboard)
if chars > 500 then
    do shell script "afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Funk.aiff"
else
    tell application "System Events"
        delay 1
        keystroke (get the clipboard)
    end tell
end if
```

The idea is that it'll type out anything on my clipboard, which is helpful when logging into servers and other things that have secure fields. Has something changed in 10.12.2 or 10.12 in general, recently? This was working just fine a couple of weeks ago, but now it's randomly capitalizing letters in the output.

I've tried removing everything but the following, along with changing the delay to no avail:

```
tell application "System Events"
    delay 1
    keystroke (get the clipboard)
end tell
```

I appreciate any help. If this isn't the right place for this, I'll be glad to move it but I don't believe it to be system related. I've tested this in Automator and the result is the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[Apparently this is a known issue with 10.12.2 since the beta.](https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/16313)

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround for this known issue.

You can use `keystroke` one character at a time, with a slight delay between each character, and that seems to do the trick:

```
repeat with letter in (get the clipboard)
    keystroke letter
    delay 5.0E-4
end repeat
```

So far as the delay between each character, `5.0E-4` seems to be enough for me, but your mileage may vary. If it doesn't work every time, play with that delay and see what works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference - MacOS Catalina

I had this very same issue and fix it by rebooting the Mac .. not sure why ..but there you have it.

Tried several options like using ascii key and pause each character.. dind't work .. reverted to keystroke and rebooted Mac .. done

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time ago now but I've just experienced what looked like the same issue. However the cause for me turned out to be that the Caps lock operates independently on the built in keyboard vs my Cherry KC 6000 Slim and the script used the onboard keyboard to determine whether caps lock was on :facepalm: