# The keystroke command in applescript can't identify case

Tags: applescript, keystroke

```
tell application "iTerm" to activate
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTerm"
   keystroke "Lsj!"
end tell
```

I want know how can i get the right way to enter some character. keystroke command can't identify case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AppleScript keystroke sometimes capitalizing letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227700/applescript-keystroke-sometimes-capitalizing-letters)

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
set the clipboard to "Lsj!" as text
tell application "iTerm" to activate
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTerm"
    keystroke (the clipboard)
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

wch1zpink's answer should work.

You can also write out the letters individually if needed

```
    keystroke "l" using {shift down} -- uppercase
    keystroke "sj!" -- lowercase
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work

```
tell application "iTerm" to activate
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTerm"
key code 37 using {shift down}
key code 1
key code 38
end tell
```